# Creating binary for go module without a main function

Tags: go

I'm working on a module library. It does not have a main function. I want this library to be available to external users however before I ship I want to provide the binary directly to some clients.

Since the module doesnt have a main package or main function (for example purpose lets say the package is "test"), when I do go build or go install, it does not produce a binary.

I did `go build -o test` but I am not able to execute that binary.

I'd like to generate a binary that I can hand to the client, and the client should be able to put directly into their `go/bin/` directory. Upon placing it there, they should be able to import my library and start testing the code.

Is it even possible to do something like this in Go? I'd like to do this step before we publish to a public repository

Comment: If I understand the question right, https://pkg.go.dev/plugin may be what you want.

Comment: For the plugin approach, the user also needs enough types/info to type-assert the `Symbol` (`any`/`interface{}`) values that `plugin.Lookup` returns into functions, values, etc. that they can use. That might consist of a package distributed as Go source that either hides the `plugin` aspect entirely (it looks like it implements the functionality, but pushes the real work down to loaded plugins) or just declares the types needed at the interface boundary.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28152) for rationale for dropping support for binary-only packages (which would have done what you want to a degree). An obfuscater ([example (not sure if this outputs source or just the executable)](https://github.com/burrowers/garble)) may provide another option.

Comment: Your requirements are contradictory. Just set up a second module with a package main (importing your library), build that and ship.